How are applications where any command can be run CLI, but also has a UI element, structured?
Sorry if the title sounds too broad, I'll try to clarify. I am trying to understand the structure of applications that have a GUI, but any action can also be run from a CLI (either integrated in the GUI, like AutoCAD (reference picture), or simply by launching the entire application in CLI, circumventing the GUI altogether). Having worked with several such programs, I noticed that any manipulation of GUI elements automatically generates a command that shows up in the CLI, which implies that GUI inputs (for example textboxes) are not binded to some underlying data, but instead write values through arguments of CLI commands to modify that underlying data. I assume that reading data works in the same way (through data retrieval commands).
This seems like a very different approach from the modern binding-based UI approach (like typically done with WPF) that seems to be very popular nowadays. It seems that GUI being a runner for CLI commands would make it more difficult to build the GUI, but having an integrated CLI (like in that AutoCAD example) seems like a great convenience for the user. But I could be wrong, maybe these two approaches are not at odds.
My question is, can anyone explain how such applications are structured, and what are the best practices on designing them? Are my assumptions in the ballpark? I tried researching this, but I probably don't know what this kind of design called, so I didn't find much. Any links, resources or just a clarification of what I need to search for would be greatly appreciated.

A high level picture, for context: Even in WPF, where you're data-binding to the ViewModel, you may be calling an underlying service (local or remote) to actually execute some action. In that case the binding helps keep UI manipulations in sync with the underlying input model, but when calling those services, you would take that data, perhaps transform to a form that better fits the service, and pass it along as arguments, and then the service would do the actual work and produce a response. The service role can be played by a CLI tool - it's just that the invoking mechanism is different.

There's not generally a single answer to this question.  There are many ways to structure programs with multiple interfaces (command, GUI, web, etc) and in many cases the structure will be influenced by what the first or "main" interface is intended to be.

Another fun option not worth a full answer: the Python click library has a BaseCommand.to_info_dict to "Gather information that could be useful for a tool generating user-facing documentation." It works pretty well for making little interfaces to interact with custom cli tools!


I noticed that any manipulation of GUI elements automatically generates a command that shows up in the CLI, which implies that GUI inputs (for example textboxes) are not binded to some underlying data, but instead write values through arguments of CLI commands to modify that underlying data

That's one way to do it, but not the only way. Let's use a simple example of approving an order request.
The CLI version could be myapp approve 12345. The UI version could be either a textbox (to input the order ID) and an approve button, or that approve button could be placed on the order details page (so the order ID is inherently known by the UI).
Somewhere in the code, you will find a method along the lines of public void ApproveOrder(int orderId). We won't explore its implementation for the sake of brevity.
Now, there are two ways these components all interact:

There is no clear winner between these two. The main difference here is whether the UI is intended to be a wrapper around the CLI (i.e. the CLI tools are always needed), or a replacement of the CLI (i.e. the CLI tools don't offer anything that's always needed).
That's contextual, and often an artefact of subjective design decisions made during the development process.
git is a good example here as one that favors the daisy chain. The git CLI is always required, because it is generally expected to integrate into externals tooling (IDEs). Because of this, the CLI already provides a full user interface, and thus git GUIs tend to just wrap themselves around that existing interface instead of trying to re-invent it.
However, a daisy chain would be disruptive if the underlying code is expected to dynamically generate images. Not that you can't e.g. pass a URL to the generated image via a CLI, but you very quickly start painting yourself in a corner with this, whereas option 2 removes the "must work via CLI" constraint that option 1 inherently entails.

Thank you very much, this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. The way you described it, distributed logic approach seems less risky. Are there any other advantages/disadvantages to using daisy chain approach if your software will not be integrated into other softwares/toolings? For example, I am speculating why AutoCAD devs chose the daisy chain approach, and can't seem to find a good reason.

Also, while the distributed logic approach is pretty clear, daisy chain approach still raises a lot of questions, like binding data to UI elements or retrieving it back via commands to display in the UI, etc. Are there any resources on designing applications this way? I tried to google it with the terms you used, but I'm not finding much.

Git GUIs typically don't wrap the git CLI tool itself, but instead libgit2, the more permissively licensed reimplementation of the core git logic.

@Justin8051: AutoCad's history reaches back to 1982, before graphical user interfaces became popular (at least the kind of GUIs as we see them today). You will find a Youtube video how the user interface looked like at version 1.0 here. As you see, most operations were indeed textual commands. The modern GUI elements came later and were build on-top of that. Such architectural decisions made in early versions are rarely discarded later.

@DocBrown ah yes, the good old days when AutoCAD was driven by text files containing commands and output files containing drawings in postscript format. The menu effectively did little but act as a way to allow the user to select input and output files and locations and that was about it.

"There is no clear winner between these two" - well, I am not that sure. My experience with adding GUIs to CLIs which were not designed for GUI usage in the first place have told me the that that the biggest issue with option 1 is processing the response from a command. Responses, especially error responses, are often not treated like a stable API. But YMMV.

Jgit does not use libgit AFAIK

IMO the daisy chain make little sense unless the CLI is out of your control. The GUI is structured, but in order to go through the CLI, it has to serialize to strings (with all the pains associated with string manipulation), then deserialize back. Your image example is simply a special case of serialization/deserialization.

@DocBrown I see, that explains it. It seems to me that this kind of applications (GUI + integrated CLI) fell out of favor these days, although personally as a user I find that very unfortunate, I love them because of how convenient they are for advanced users. Which is the whole reason for my post - wondering if there is an easy way to implement that in my applications without doubling the work for myself when it comes to tests, maintainability, etc.

@Justin8051 "Distributed logic approach seems less risky" -- one hidden risk here is decoherence. In the distributed logic approach, it's easy to get into a situation where taking the "same" action in the GUI or the CLI results in different outcomes.

@DanielWagner yes, I suspected this issue as well, I mentioned this concern in some of my other comments. This is basically the whole point of my post - trying to find a smarter solution that doesn't have the downsides of daisy chain/distributed logic approaches. Perhaps I'm chasing unicorns here, not sure yet.

@Justin8051 I don't think it fell out of favour. Games traditionally have a way to enter (cheat) commands, chat apps have slash commands (e.g. Teams, Slack), IDEs have command bars (e.g. vscode), even browsers accept command inputs (e.g. Vivaldi). They just don't have a traditional CLI.

@DanielWagner that depends on your API (backend) design. Nothing in the CLI should have actual business logic, it should take the arguments from the command line, parse them and forward them to the API method; while yes you could have someone that ignores this constraint and implements logic in the CLI part, you can have that with daisy chaining too- just the other way around: someone could add logic into the graphical UI layer after or before calling the CLI method.

@Justin8051: no, it only explains why option #1 fell out of favor.

@FrankHopkins, so if I understand this right, whichever method I choose (daisy chain or distributed logic), I should have the API layer there as well that acts as an interface between application core and CLI/GUI, correct? Is that the right way to separate concerns? I admit I never done API in any of my applications, do you know of any learning resources on how to do it properly (in C#, desktop development)?

@Justin8051 what Flater outlined here as backend logic would be your API level; that can but does not need to be an interface in the more technical sense. It's just some collection of methods both the CLI and GUI implementation can somehow call and that does all the business logic. How to technically do that depends on your tech stack and requirements. In the simplest case where you have just one program with one way to execute an operation from a GUI  and one way to run that command from a CLI , it can be as simple as just being some class with some public methods.

@PhilipKendall Good callout because it actually proves my point: there's clearly a free choice here to be made.

@DocBrown I guess I should have said "there no clear universal winner here", though that point seemed implicitly made, especially with the last paragraph calling out that a CLI can become a blocker for what is feasible. I was also working under the assumption that the CLI was still in active development, not that a GUI had to be built around a CLI that was designed without GUI-wrapping in mind and which could no longer be touched.

Also, just to address the point touched on by several people: I don't like CLIs as a baseline. I agree with all the limitations of a CLI, if chosen for no particular reason. But the question here seemed very much rooted in that there is an established CLI (the question is no "should I also build a CLI?"), which suggests that whatever OP's current use case is, a CLI can meaningfully capture its interactions with the user.

To extend @FrankHopkins's point about "backend logic" being the API; he's correctly summarized it. There are additional considerations whether you'd (a) have the CLI and GUI call the same instance or (b) are happy for the CLI and GUI to merely load the same library locally in their own runtime. That's a different question unrelated to this topic. For this topic, the point I was trying to make is that somewhere, you want to have logic that is reusable and doesn't need to be written twice. That's what I referred to as the "backend logic" to keep it abstract.

I don't think the daisy chain is meant to imply that the GUI must execute CLI commands exactly as they are written, but that it calls on the CLI implementation close to the top of its abstraction stack, not in the middle.

@CriticizingIsraelnotallowed I'm not sure what point you're making here as executing CLI commands would always fall squarely in the camp of the CLI component in either case.

@CriticizingIsraelnotallowed: it is debatable whether "a GUI which calls on the CLI implementation close to the top of it's abstraction stack" falls under option #1 or option #2.

@FrankHopkins, thank you for clarification. This question might be a bit off-topic, but if my application is structured this way, this backend logic being separate from CLI/GUI, and probably referring to it only through an abstract interface that CLI/GUI must implement to ensure proper decoupling - can I also somehow expose that backend logic as a true API, so that a 3rd party devs could write their own GUI or automation tools? How would I do that? I'm writing in C#, compiled to .exe files, so I assume I would also have to compile it to a .dll library? Any learning resources on that?

@Justin8051: That follow up question is way too broad even if you posted it as a question alone, let alone as a tack-on to this existing question. This is turning into a "design my application for me" question, which start being a request for free work rather than for information. Your goals are good but it requires more legwork from your end.

@Flater, sorry, I did not intend it that way. Not expecting anyone to design it for me, just looking for learning materials to learn how to do it myself, thought someone might have a suggestions for some books or something, since what I'm looking for was made very apparent through this discussion. Sorry again.

@Flater the point is the GUI can call SelectCommand("foo") instead of actually forming and re-parsing the string "select foo" and still fall under the first architecture. The latter is just an invitation for command injection attacks.

@Flater in no way disagreeing with the general principle, but the statement "The git CLI is always required" is not strictly correct; absolutely GUIs wrap themselves around an existing interface, it just happens to be a more useful interface than the CLI interface.

I would argue that this is not what is commonly called CLI, but a Console in an already running GUI that provides CLI.
Console is typically openable from within the GUI and allows to issue commands to the underlying engine. This is often used in games, where there is a game logic engine running under the hood. Games would often have this separation between logic engine and GUI since it allows a number of neat features:

game logic engine can run in a deterministic manner, where exact same inputs lead to exact same results
replays become easy - just record player input and repeat it anew to get the replay
multiplayer becomes easy - exchange player inputs and get the same result for every player
in-game scripting - modders can make the levels interactive and unique with ease
in-game console - players and testers can access all sorts of wild things on request
testing - running the game with a specially crafted script to reproduce bugs or generate data for analytics

Now you might already have some clue of how it might be structured - have a separation between logic engine that runs by itself and a bunch of control inputs coming from GUI, replay, script, multiplayer peers, console.


Using daisy-chain could be double work (that could also be suboptimal in performance-critical scenarios). It makes little sense to assemble textual command script in GUI subsystem just to pass it to the Console subsystem to be parsed and converted back to method call in the logic engine.


Thank you for your answer. I am interested in learning more about how both methods (CLI and GUI) should be connected to the underlying engine to ensure that both work equally, and that every action/command has a representation both in CLI and GUI. Seems to me that it might be a lot of largely redundant work, especially for testing, and easy to forget to implement some commands in CLI or GUI. The daisy-chain method that Flater described in another answer seems to help enforcing equal functioning and less tests, but it comes with some other disadvantages. I'm eager to learn more.

"that every action/command has a representation both in CLI and GUI" - generally this cant be enforced. Any method could be forgotten or short-circuited or invoked incorrectly. You will need automated tests for that in any case, cos it's possible to forget or misplace anything in any(!) Interface. The more functionality you have the more tests you need :-)

Regarding terminology: IMHO "CLI" is the common term for the concept as a whole. "Console" is just the name for the window or screen area provided for the CLI's I/O.

@DocBrown agreed. I got the impression OP was asking specifically about applications with Console CLI, not the generic CLI apps (git and its wrappers).

@Kromster Yes, that is correct. My main concern is adding integrated CLI in a GUI application without unnecessarily complicating the development, tests and maintenance. Not sure if that is at all possible.

@Kromster Just wanted to add, thank you for expanding your question, the infographics are very useful. Interesting that there is the Core API layer, rather than CLI API and GUI accessing core engine directly. But I suppose it makes sense, even more separation of concerns. Sorry to be asking this, but do you know of any documentation, examples or literature about how to properly write that Core API layer? I googled it for a while now, but can't seem to find much in C#, everything API-related is all about web API (ASP.NET), which seems to be a very different thing than what you're describing.

@Justin8051 Core API has to be there since the CLI still needs to parse the textual input and convert it to function with parameters calls - which is Core API. Regarding the question - it's hard to answer without knowing MUCH more details about your app. Generally - start writing with Model/GUI separation in mind and implement your Console early, so that you can code both GUI and Console against the Core.

Proper separation of concerns takes care of it all. Rather than handling all the stuff that that button press needs to accomplish in the event handler for the button, have the event handler just do enough to pass on the actual command to the same method that's triggered when entering a CLI or console command to do that operation.
So e.g. you made an approveOrder(orderId, authorisationToken, timestamp) method to handle approving orders. From your GUI's event handler, you call this method after calculating a timestamp and retrieving the other parameters. From the console you do the same, from a command line interface to the system you do the same too. Only potential difference would be the source of the data passed to the method.

Thank you for your answer, if I understand correctly, this is the Option 2 from Flater's answer. If I assume correctly, this means that since GUI does not generate CLI commands, it is up to the developer to develop both ways of interacting with the application separately, and test them separately, with no real enforcement/assurance that both methods work equivalently. Is that correct?

@Justin8051, there is indeed no magic bullet to enforce correct separation of concerns. It takes attention from the developers and needs to be checked by reviews.

@Justin8051 a strong design helps, you will have to be diligent to stay on course and not slide into the "let's do this the easy way quickly, it'll only be this once" trap as that way leads to disaster. But you also need to be pragmatic and not fall into the trap of turning your system into such an unwieldy layer cake of interfaces between components that it becomes impossible to handle (I've seen a system where for example a single button press took 5 minutes to lead to a response on screen because it was so poorly written there were literally hundreds of layer transitions for an interaction

@Justin8051 you can always write tests to verify the same behaviour (though writing tests for a GUI can be a challenge in itself if you really want to include the GUI interaction in the testing...) but ultimately if a programmer in the project wants to break the design they can adjust whatever safeguards you built in... so you need to make the design clear and have people commit to it (or control it via merge requests and the like). Tests can help in communicating the desired behaviour but nothing can enforce it.

@Justin8051 - the point is that the GUI and the CLI are peers... they're both user interfaces wrapped around some core functionality. And that core functionality doesn't know anything about user interfaces... it's just a library of operations for a user interface (or even something else, a scripting tool or something) to call.

Making them peers loses some very nice functionality often found in the systems where the GUI has to use the CLI... such as action history (as real commands that can be executed again)

Applications like this use in general some variant of the command pattern as core way to operate on the model. The GUI operations generate internal commands, and CLI commands are just a way to generate the same commands. It is then easy to systematically display all commands performed in textual way.
In the case of Autocad, there's also a programmatic way to operate on the model, via AutoLisp. Although it has a different syntax, it generates in the end the same primitive commands.
Some context also: Autocad was there before Windows was lauched. At that time, GUI operations were not a native OS feature but had to be implemented in application. It was not uncommon in that time to start project with a quick text interface to manipulate the model and get some solid foundation before going to develop the GUI, which required a lot more work (every mouse producer had its own drivers and API, and in the case of autocad there where all these tablet producers which used absolute positions instead of relative ones, so different worlds of devices that are nowadays gently hidden behind standardized API)

If you have a "model-view-controller" internal structure, and especially if you use the "command pattern" internally, then the command line becomes just another form of View.
This can arise fairly naturally if you have had to build complicated tests for the application logic. In order to get it right, it will have been necessary to separate it properly from the GUI and run lots of unit tests, which necessarily run headless.

Yes, that is the kind of structure I typically go for. Thing is, having CLI in addition to this creates risk of decoherence between GUI and CLI operations and a lot of additional tests/maintenance required. Daniel Wagner described this issue really well in a comment a few answers above yours. I am wondering if there is a way to avoid that risk and extra work by somehow enforcing coherence.

@Justin8051 If you are looking to emulate the feature you describe in AutoCAD and have every GUI command have an equivalent CLI command, you really need to design that in.  While it's not necessary to have the GUI execute the CLI commands, I would recommend building your logic such that it's isomorphic to the CLI and then layer your GUI onto that.  That way when you build a command with the GUI, you can easily convert that into the corresponding CLI command.  It's easier to build something in a GUI that you can't reproduce in a CLI than the other way around.

@JimmyJames Good advice, thank you. Passing commands/variables from GUI to the application core via CLI is one thing, but what about getting data back? Like, some value changes in the core, and GUI instantly responds by updating that value display, which is typically done with binding? Also retrieving more complicated data, like data tables, pictures, etc.? Should all the return info operate through the CLI layer as well before reaching GUI, or should it be done directly? And what about binding, like in WPF - that's a no-go here for the sake of consistency, right?

@Justin8051 It's hard to say without knowing a lot more about your application. I can imagine a lot of applications supporting CLI commands with no CLI display, other than a status.  For example, if I run CLI command to invert the colors of an image, what should the CLI show?  I can also imagine executing CLI commands which update a GUI. I'm not exactly sure what binding is in the context, but I would generally want a GUI to update based on events and the CLI output to be synchronous.

Having the GUI run CLI commands is a possibility, but it's not necessarily the best or most common approach. While you may not have a choice if you need to wrap an already existing program, my impression is that when the CLI and GUI are developed together by the same team, it's more common for both to call some kind of underlying API. For example, a Python program myapp may have myapp.cli and myapp.gui modules that implement the user interfaces, with other modules implementing the core logic.
In the simplest case, that API can be internal to your program. Then you can change it without having to worry about backwards compatibility with code that you don't own, but it's harder for other people to write additional UIs.
One level of separation up, you can expose the core logic of your program as a library with a public API — for example, a Python package or a dynamically linked C library.
Finally, for the strongest separation, you can make your program a server that exposes the core functionality over an inter-process communication method like HTTP or JSON-RPC, and manage the UIs as separate projects. In the Linux world, this is commonly done using D-Bus.

Thank you, some very good info here, I was wondering about API as well, but didn't want to complicate my initial question even further. You gave a good idea to enforce cohesion between CLI and GUI through a common interface, I hadn't considered that. I suppose it can't cover everything (like for example, displaying a picture in CLI and GUI is so different that there's not much for interface to enforce), but at least it would enforce that the picture display command is implemented rather than forgotten in either module.

The GUI is input and output, as such it is technically irrelevant to the logical functioning of any application.
I work with several web based applications that have a shared convention of having two functions for every page - called Gather and Scatter.  Scatter is called to set the initial condition of the page, it creates any data models that the pages uses, sets any bindings and so forth. Gather takes the data from the page and does any additional validation or updates to the submitted data prior to doing the actual work of the page.
I also work with other web based applications that have different conventions, where the data bindings and data flow is handled differently, including a PWA (persistent web application).
What they all have in common is that there is always something between the UI interaction and data persistence.  Whether they are MVC, MVVM, MVP, Clean or whatever, nothing mixes the UI and the data code.  There is always somewhere where the UI elements have been turned into data and that data is going to be acted on.  And that somewhere is always accessible outside of the UI code.
The main functional difference between a CLI application and a GUI is how convenient it is to both collect and display large amount of disparate data.
As long as your code is properly separated, once you have the data, it should be pretty easy.
